# Regex to pick a part of a word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like this:

```
my text has $1 per Lap to someone.
```

Could anyone tell me how to pick the `per` part from it. I know how to pick the `$` amount. It's like this:

```
new Regex(@"\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Match(s.Comment1).Groups[0].ToString()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: you want to match `$`, a number, `per`, and a word; capturing the number and word?

Comment: What the type of `per`?

Comment: @Kasra it's just a string type.

Comment: @Richard Nope,I just need to pick or check whether there is a `per` part on the above text.

Comment: Would `(per)` not do what you are looking for? or just checking if the string contains "per"? what is it you are trying to do with it?

Comment: @Sayse just checking if the string contains "per".

Comment: Then do that instead, you don't need regex

Comment: @Sayse Can you tell me how to do it without regex ? Thanks.

Comment: [String contains](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=string+contains+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=f81JVYCKD8n3asCzgXg)

Comment: @Sayse I'm sorry.It should comes after the `$` amount.

Comment: @Sampath: Certainly it is possible to do it another way, but it will just take more time and more lines of code. Regex is surely the quickest way here. Also, it is difficult to quickly check only specific string parts in a case-insensitive way. With regex, we can set the `(?i:)` group around the subpattern to enforce case-insensitivity. Maybe with just 1 word it is still not so convincing, but it is a valid way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that `per` is a string type the following simple regex can does the job for you :

```
\$\d+\s([a-zA-Z]+)
```

But if the `per` is contain digits you can use `\w` that match word characters :

```
\$\d+\s(\w+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wK9zG7/2)

*Note* that in this case `per` is in the first capture group and you need to extract the first group.

Also you can use a positive look behind if you dont want to use `grouping` :

```
(?<=\$\d+\s)[a-zA-Z]+
```

If the `per` is a special word you can check with following regex :

```
(?<=\$\d+\s)per
```

Something like :

```
var per_str = new Regex(@'(?<=\$\d+\s)per').Match(str).Groups[0].Value;
if (per_str != ''){
#dostuff
}
```

Comment: On your demo where I saw that it picks both `$` and `per` parts.But I need to pick only the `per` part.

Comment: @Sampath Yeah its the whole of match as you are using capture grouping you need to extract the first group. `Match(s.Comment1).Groups[1]`

Comment: I have used alternate way.But it picks not only `per` others as well.It's like this.Let's say I have a text like this `my text has $1 to Lap to someone.`.Then it picks `to`.How can I avoid to pick others ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sampath So do you want `Lap` or also `someone`?

Comment: No.I just need to check whether above text is having `per` part only.Others should not pick.Thanks.

Comment: @Sampath So you mean that `per` is a special word?

Comment: I have used this `(?<=\$\d+\s)per` where without Groups.Still it's working.But on your example you have put Groups.Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Sampath I think you are pretty unfamiliar with regex! you can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: @Sampath I have explained the details for you, and if you have found your answer you can tell this to community with vote and [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Misunderstanding here.Sorry about that.You gave me the really good answer and thanks a lot for that.But I just need to know whether can I use it without Groups ? That is the only question.B'cos I have used it without Groups and it works.I got little bit confuse hence on the last example you used the Groups with this `(?<=\$\d+\s)per`.Is that need or not ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sampath You're welcome, actually the last part is not capture group its the positive look-behind and regex engine does't interpret it as group! its the boundary around look-behind!

Comment: OK sure.Got it.Thanks a lot for your continues support.Keep up the Great work ! :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you have multiple substrings you need inside a larger string, you can use capturing groups.

To obtain the `per` part, use the following regex and grab the `Groups[2].Value`:

```
var str = "my text has $1 per Lap to someone. ";
var per_str = new Regex(@"(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\p{L}+)").Match(str).Groups[2].Value;
```

Output:

[image]

The regex to capture `per` is `\p{L}+` where `\p{L}` captures all Unicode letters (e.g. `ф`, `ё`), not just Latin script.

To get the number part, use the same regex, but grab `Groups[1].Value`:

```
var num_str = new Regex(@"(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\p{L}+)").Match(str).Groups[1].Value;
```

Output:

[image]

*And another tip*: **compile your regex** first if you plan to use it multiple times during your app execution:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\p{L}+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var per_str = rx.Match(str).Groups[2].Value;
var num_str = rx.Match(str).Groups[1].Value;
```

In case you need just a number after `$`, just put the opening round bracket after it in the regex: `@"\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\p{L}+)"`.

And to get all groups in 1 go, you can use

```
var groups = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => new { num = p.Groups[1].Value, per = p.Groups[2].Value }).ToList();
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you just want to match `per` after the number, you can use `@"(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(per)"` or (case-insensitive) `@"(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*((?i:per\b))"`

Comment: But it picks not only `per` others as well.It's like this.Let's say I have a text like this `my text has $1 to Lap to someone.`.Then it picks `to`.How can I avoid to pick others ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a literal "per": `@"(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(per)\b"`. However, I do not see the point in a capturing group, then, since you know it is "per". Unless it can be in lower or upper case. Then, use `@"(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*((?i:per)\b)"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+)\S+
```

This should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sayse said, you don't need a Regex here. I made two solutions without.

Check the [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IzlAf2) or read the code :

```
public static void Main()
{
    var s = "my text has $1 per Lap to someone.";

    Console.WriteLine(Test(s));
    Console.WriteLine(Test2(s));
}

static object Test(string s)
{           
    var tab = s.Remove(s.IndexOf(" Lap"))       // remove everything after " Lap" 
               .Substring(s.IndexOf(" $") + 2)  // remove everything before " $"
               .Split(' ');

    return new { Amount = tab[0], Per = tab[1] };
}

static object Test2(string s)
{
    var tab = s.Split(' ');
    var amount = tab.Single(t => t.StartsWith("$")).Substring(1);
    var per = tab[Array.FindIndex(tab, t => t.StartsWith("$")) + 1];

    return new { Amount = amount, Per = per };
}
```

output

```
{ Amount = 1, Per = per }
{ Amount = 1, Per = per }
```

Comment: Yeah, as I said, instead of 3 lines, we have a gazillion.

Comment: In `Test()`, there is only 2 lines and you could do it in only one if your return directly the array `tab`.